# Generating large simulations and inserting the same array multiple times into another array at different locations

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, numba

I am working to generate a monte carlo simulation for oil wells. The end goal is to have all the wells with a smoothed probabilistic production curve. I have optimized what I can, but each of the 3 apply statements I am listing take so much time when I use my full dataset and the number of simulations I want. (Hours) The code I included is has 10 iterations. If you crank it up to 10,000 which is the goal it really starts to drag.

I have generated a Panda that has all the future wells I want to model with a probability of that well being chosen next to be drilled.

I then created a panda where I grouped everything into the categories I want to use to figure out the order that the model will choose the wells. So my "timing" panda contains my categories and an array of every index of those wells in those categories and an array of the well's probabilities.

This all is done in a few seconds. The next part works, but gets very slow.

Next I use a numpy generator choice with percentages to randomly generate the order of the wells for i simulations. As other posts have noted @njit does not work with the probability array. The result is 1 dimension of the array is the order that the wells will be chosen by each category, and the other dimension is each simulation. There are about 150 categories, and 10,000s of wells in each categories. I am hoping to run 10,000 simulations.

- a is an array of indexes of wells that can be chosen
- size is the length of that array
- per is the probability that each well will get chosen

Next I link my timing panda to my panda with all of the wells in it. This attaches the previous array to the wells array. Then I search this array for the well index to figure out for each simulation when that specific well is going to get run. This generates a 1d array with what order that well is going be drilled in each simulation.

This function gets called on 100,000s of wells and as I increase the number of simulations it really slows down.

- order is an array of the order each well is drilled per simulation
- index is the index of that well

The final difficulty I am having is the averaging out the production curve for the wells. I have how much oil will be produced by each well per month. I need to insert that curve into the array at each point when the well is drilled, then average all of those values together to get the average production of the well given all the simulations.

I have also tried creating an np.zeros array then using the np.insert function, but I could not figure out how to insert an array multiple times without a loop and generating the initial array of 0's took longer than the current method I had. (I overcame inserting the array multiple times by covering everything to a string, inserting the type curve as a string then converting back to an array of numbers, but this did not seem efficient). I need to have the number of leading 0's

- order is the time in months that each well will get drilled
- curve is the production curve passed as a list
- m is the highest value of the months that the well is drilled in all simulations

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import datetime
import math

def TimingGenerator(a, size, p):
  i = 10
  g = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64())
  order = np.concatenate([g.choice(a=a, size=size, replace=False, p=p) for z in range(i)]).reshape(i, size)
  return order

@njit
def OrderGenerator(order, index):
  result = np.where(order == index)[1]
  return result

def CurveAverager(order, curve, m):
  matrix = np.array([[0] * math.ceil(i) + curve + [0] * int((m - math.ceil(i))) for i in order])
  result = np.mean(matrix, axis=0)
  return result

begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()

size = 8000
g = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64())
a = g.choice(20_000, size=size, replace=False)
p = np.random.randint(1,100, size=size)
p = p/np.sum(p)

for i in range(150):
  q = TimingGenerator(a,size,p)

print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)

index = np.amin(q)
for i in range(100000):
  order = OrderGenerator(q, index)

print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)

order = order / 15
curve = list(range(600, 0, -1))

for i in range(20000):
  avgcurve = CurveAverager(order, curve, size)

print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)
```

Thanks for any help you can offer. I am willing to greatly alter my code if you can think of anything to help speed it up. Not sure if there is a better way to apply probabilities and smooth out the production curve which is really the end goal.

Cheers.

Comment: This is clearly a well-researched question, but it is not minimal or reproducible. If I were you, I would profile the code, find the bottleneck and ask a question about that, including some fake data that others can use.

Comment: On a more practical side, `np.choice` can be slow without replacement. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60418136/python-fast-way-to-sample-data-from-array-when-sample-size-changes) for one possible workaround.

Comment: Last thing - applying numba decorators to high-level functions like TimingGenerator or OrderGenerator may add little speed, or even make the program slower. Numba cannot magically rewrite numpy code to make it more efficient. You could test each function with and without the decorator to see what works best.

Comment: Thanks @hilberts_drinking_problem. I played around with the jit and you were correct on two of the functions it was slightly slows. The one I could apply njit was significantly quicker though. I updated to np.generator for the random choice and it did speed things up about from 9 min to 8 min for 10,000 simulations. I also tried to get a working set of code. Not sure if it meets your criteria. Cheers.